# Flash - alternative to ComboBox control

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need a drop-down for my form. It looks like [ComboBox control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa9.html) is what I need to use. It works but it adds 50k to my SWF.  I'm wondering if there is stuff that I can do to mitigate such file size increase. Or are there other alternatives to ComboBox control?

Comment: Are you really that concerned with 50k? Also make sure you are looking at the production version of the swf not the debug version as the debug version compiles differently and is generally much more bloated.

Comment: Yeah. It's a production swf not debug. I'm trying to see if I can optimize my application as much as I can, hence the concern with size. 50k is about 7% of my current swf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Write your own simplistic ComboBox implementation that could be smaller, because it won't compile all framework dependencies. Though it can be non-trivial task, especially if you want to have similar flexibility as standard components provide out of the box.
2. Find another UI solution for your problem if applicable.
3. Use HTML  tag outside your Flash application and communicate between HTML and Flash using ExternalInterface if applicable.

Comment: For option #3, is there an HTML tag I can use in my Flash application? Like a select html tag? I know you can add simple html code to a TextField control that does some formatting and images. I don't think it can handle a select tag though. http://adobe.ly/PZDzrf

Comment: @dev.e.loper By html tag outside the app he is talking about using a select tag in the web page itself and then have that select talk to the flash app.

Answer (score 0):

I might try [Liquid Components](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=137) and see what the difference is.

Comment: well, never mind that. liquid component combobox just extends regular ComboBox.